# Memory Leak Troubleshooting for addSubview

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, addsubview

What is the proper way to prevent memory leaks when using addSubview? I am getting complaints from Instruments that there is a leak in this code. What am I doing wrong?

Example Code:

my.h

```
@interface MyCustomControl : UIControl {
    UILabel *ivarLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel       *ivarLabel;
```

my.m

```
@synthesize ivarLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        self.ivarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 10, 10)];
        [self addSubview:self.ivarLabel];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [ivarLabel release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
  self.ivarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 10, 10)];
```

Do this:

```
  ivarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 10, 10)];
```

The first snippet would work in ARC.

**But why?**

A setter internally (`self.ivarLabel = ...`) will have the same logic as this:

```
-(void)setIvarLabel:(UILabel *)newLabel {
    if (ivarLabel != value) {
        [ivarLabel release];
        ivarLabel = [newLabel retain];
    }
}
```

You can see that the `alloc` you do (`[UILabel alloc]`) plus the retain done inside the `if`, will create a retain count of 2. That minus the `release` on the `dealloc`, give you 1. That's why you have a leak.

Comment: Then in my call to addSubview, would I use: [self addSubview:self.ivarLabel] or [self addSubview:ivarLabel] ?

Comment: In that case, doesn't matter because you are using the get method (remember when you use `self.something` you are actually using the setter or getter methods of that property).